# How does one remove an epoxy metal to metal joint without using heat?

Tags: adhesive, epoxy

I have a threaded rod (3/8" coarse thread) that has a couple of nuts on it, glues in place with epoxy.
This is part of jig that I have built and which is supposed to create linear movement when the rod rotates. The problem is that the rotation is counter intuitive and rotating the rod toward the used makes the moving part advancing in the right direction (when it should be the other way)

I might keep it like this and use another gear to actually speed up the rotation or if I can easily unglue it I could fix the above

Comment: There is no universal epoxy, and therefore no universal solvent. Name the epoxy . Then either Google for the specific solvent or post it here and somebody can do that for  you.

Comment: Not really sure if this qualifies as home improvement.

Comment: You might want a left handed threaded rod to get the movement you want.  It might be a custom threading job.

Comment: I could remove the existing one and install it back and switch the two ends

Comment: Most **cured** epoxies have no solvent.

Comment: A (normal) right-hand thread will still be a fight-hand thread after you switch it around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely application of a big enough (long-handle wise, correctly fitted to the nuts) pair of wrenches will break one of the two free. Epoxy isn't magic, and few people bother to prepare a joint for epoxy in a manner that comes close to maximizing strength. Steel will be considerably stronger. Using a sharp blade and/or pointed tool to remove excess epoxy on the exposed threads by picking or cutting it off will ease the process.

Then you can jam two nuts together with no epoxy for something to hold onto while you break the other epoxied nut free. You might even learn from doing that that you don't need epoxy to hold nuts in place, since jam nuts (or regular nuts applied as jam nuts are) will do that with only a pair of wrenches needed for installation and removal.